# Creating an array while passing it as an argument in Java

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, arguments, argument-passing

Is there a way to create an array of  objects as part of a constructor or method?  I'm really not sure how to word this, so I've included an example.  I have an enum, and one of the fields is an array of numbers.  Here is what I tried:

```
public enum KeyboardStuff {

    QWERTY(1, {0.5f, 1.3f, 23.1f}, 6);
    DVORAK(5, {0.1f, 0.2f, 4.3f, 1.1f}, 91);
    CHEROKEE(2, {22.0f}, 11);

    private int number, thingy;
    private float[] theArray;

    private KeyboardStuff(int i, float[] anArray, int j) {
        // do things
    }

}
```

The compiler says that the brackets { } are invalid and should be removed.  Is there a way I can pass an array as an argument without creating an array of objects beforehand?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can try with `new float[] { ... }`.

```
public enum KeyboardStuff {

    QWERTY(1, new float[] {0.5f, 1.3f, 23.1f}, 6);
    DVORAK(5, new float[] {0.1f, 0.2f, 4.3f, 1.1f}, 91);
    CHEROKEE(2, new float[] {22.0f}, 11);

    private int number, thingy;
    private float[] theArray;

    private KeyboardStuff(int i, float[] anArray, int j) {
        // do things
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following @Dave's suggest I would use a vararg

```
QWERTY(1, 6, 0.5, 1.3, 23.1);
DVORAK(5, 91, 0.1, 0.2, 4.3, 1.1);
CHEROKEE(2, 11, 22.0);

private final int number, thingy;
private final double[] theArray;

private KeyboardStuff(int number, int thingy, double... theArray) {
    // do things
}
```

It is pretty rare that using a `float` is better than using a `double`. double has less rounding error and only uses 4 more bytes.

Comment: @Dave too, I almost forgot about this.  Thank you for this solution, but I may need to create more than one Object[] parameter, so this wouldn't be ideal in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way you can pass an array without creating an array?

No, but you could use [varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) to make it mostly-invisible, although that `int` at the end might need to move.

Answer (score 1):

If using Lists's instead of arrays is an option, future versions of Java might start supporting a '[collection literals](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/186)' syntax which unfortunately doesn't seem to have made it into Java 8:

```
public enum KeyboardStuff {

    QWERTY(1, [0.5f, 1.3f, 23.1f], 6);
    DVORAK(5, [0.1f, 0.2f, 4.3f, 1.1f], 91);
    CHEROKEE(2, [22.0f], 11);

    private int number, thingy;
    private List<Float> values;

    private KeyboardStuff(int i, List<Float> values, int j) {
        // do things
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like collection literals did not make it into Java 8 either, unfortunately.